# Checking for a new date using Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a csv containing approximately 42,000 rows and 14 columns.

One of the fields is `starttime`, which contains a date and time in the format `2015-02-01 00:00:00+00`. The csv contains one week of data.

The csv has been sorted on the `starttime` field, with the oldest datetime in the first row (after the header), and the most recent in the last.

I am attempting to write a batch script that prints the contents of the entire csv row to my console whenever the date changes. Since the csv contains one week of data, I would expect to see seven lines printed.

My approach is to parse the first row's `starttime` for day and store it in a list. Then I would like to compare the day from the `starttime` in each subsequent row to the `starttime` item in the list. If the day already exists in the list, ignore the row.

As soon as the day doesn't match, add it to the list and yield the row from the csv for printing later.

So far, I have this:

```
day_holder = []

def new_date(reader):
for row in reader:
    starttime = dateutil.parser.parse(row['starttime'])

    if starttime.day not in day_holder:
        day_holder.append(starttime.day)
        yield row        
    else: 
        reader.next()

with open('the_csv.csv', 'r') as x:
    reader = csv.DictReader(x)
    for row in new_date(reader):
        print ','.join(map(row.get, reader.fieldnames))
```

But it's printing every row in the csv and crashing my machine. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You apparently haven't traced your program's flow to see what it does.  Basic debugging is a critical skill.  I applied a couple of steps myself, and it appears that your data flow with **day_holder** is correct; I think you're yielding the correct rows.  However, you need to trace this yourself: make a small test case, perhaps 5 rows with only 3 different days.  Add a **print** before the **yield** to tell you what's being returned; another just after you read, printing the **row** you got.  This will either accuse or eliminate the generator as the problem.

Comment: Also add a **print** statements in your final **for** block to see what you're actually processing.  You might find one or two other places to check.  If needed, consider splitting up your final **print** statement to validate the **join**.  ///  In the long run, learn to use a debugger that works on your development environment.  This will save a lot of time in future coding: you get to pause your program at chosen points and look at variable values.

Comment: Get rid of `else: reader.next()` which just throws a row away without checking  but otherwise (as already mentioned) your code should work. You've got some suggestions but we haven't heard back. Right now, this problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Thank you both. @tdelaney it was indeed the `else` that created the problem. Removing it results in the script producing seven records.

Comment: You could also use itertools.groupby() to group the rows by the start date.